# Accept ServerSocket connection for multiple port

Tags: java, tcp, concurrency, serversocket

```
buyerSocket = new ServerSocket(BUYER_PORT);
sellerSocket = new ServerSocket(SELLER_PORT);
Socket clientSocket = null;
while (true)
    {
        clientSocket = sellerSocket.accept();
        MultiServerThread x = new MultiServerThread(clientSocket, dat);
        x.start();

        clientSocket = buyerSocket.accept();
        MultiServerThread y = new MultiServerThread(clientSocket, dat);
        y.start();

    }
```

In this block of code, it always waits for the sellerSocket to connect first before accepting buyerSocket. Could anyone suggest a way to accept whichever come first?

As for the description of accept() - Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The method blocks until a connection is made. Should I use another method instead of accept() if I want to accept connection from multiple ports?

Comment: Why do you need two ports?

Comment: @EJP The buyer and seller (separate programs) will connect through different ports and they can send different type of commands so I have to separate the ports to differentiate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is to use multithreading, because the accept() method blocks until a connection comes in.

Comment: Not the only way.  You can also use a NIO Selector.  But certainly the simplest way.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that this was the only way using a ServerSocket from the java.net package. I haven't looked into NIO server stuff yet

Comment: Thanks, I created a Thread for reading each port and it worked but it throws BindException like 10 times for each connect, but it still runs correctly so I guess I just have to ignore the BindExceptions

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about bind exceptions, but I think that means that the port is already occupied

Comment: I moved the buyerSocket and sellerSocket outside the while loop of Thread and it solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Non Blocking IO (NIO) library for this. You can follow this nice tutorial http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/index.html

Comment: Also not the only way.

Comment: Ya. We can solve with multi-threading, the same we can achieve with Single thread using NIO.